# Ignore stage border for mouse clicks javafx

Tags: opengl, canvas, javafx

I'm making a startup manager for my music visualizer in javafx. The visualizer is written in OpenGL, and the manager feeds information into the visualizer. In the manager I have some sort of preview for the visualizer in the form of a stage only containing a canvas. On the canvas I want to draw some lines with the mouse and then pass the coordinates to OpenGL. My problem is, that if I access the `mouseEvent.getX()` coordinates, the decoration is included, which means, that the coordinates are not accurate, or shifted by the decoration. Here are some pictures to show:

[image]

The first screenshot shows the manager. Notice, that the line goes from the top left all the way down to the bottom right

[image]

The second screenshot shows the visualizer. Here, the white line doesnt go all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Can you provide some code - particularly where you are generating the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue and leave this answer just for future reference.

When trying to scale a canvas relatively, you have to be careful which measure to use.

When creating a window, the coordinate system of the `Stage` is relative to the top left of the window, including the decoration. When adding a `Node` with a fixed size, like a `Canvas` to it, the size of the `Stage` gets bigger.

So when scaling some thing relative to the `Canvas`'s size, you have to use the width and height of the `Canvas`.